# Java: Iterate over tcl dict

Tags: java, tcl

I am executing TCL code in Java. The return object is a tcl dict. How do I terate over this in Java?

There is a method called `TclDict.foreach()` but I don't understand how to use that. Where do I get the accumulator and the visitor?

I am using the tcl.lang package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visitor is the object you supply that implements the [`visit`](https://jtcl.kenai.com/apidocs/tcl/lang/TclDict.Visitor.html#visit(tcl.lang.Interp,%20java.lang.Object,%20tcl.lang.TclObject,%20tcl.lang.TclObject)) method for each key/value pair in the dictionary. The accumulator is an arbitrary object that you provide when you make the call; the visitor takes that object as an argument and returns it (or some other object) which is then passed into the next call to the visitor, or returned as a result from the iteration. It's a way of conveniently doing a fold over the contents of the dictionary; you can always use `null` if you want to just ignore it, or make the visitor always return the accumulator it was provided.

You could use `foreach` to create a `java.util.HashMap` from a `TclDict`:

```
Map<String,TclObject> makeMap(Interp interp, TclDict dict) {
    final Map<String,TclObject> map = new HashMap<>();
    TclDict.foreach(interp, null, dict, new TclDict.Visitor() {
        Object visitor(Interp interp, Object accum, TclObject key, TclObject value) {
            map.put(key.toString(), value);
            return accum;
        }
    });
    return map;
}
```

However, be aware that the semantics of `TclObject`s isn't exactly that of normal Java objects; you're advised to not modify the values or retain them for long periods of time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it now!!